# How do I determine whether the system is in "locked" state or not on the command line?

Tags: windows-10

I've waded through a million search results now, but all avoid answering my question:

How do I determine, with a terminal/cmd.exe command (or PowerShell cmdlet/script if all else fails), whether the computer is in "locked" state or not?

By "locked", I mean the user has pressed WinKey + L to get to a state where they need to enter a password to go back into the desktop.

The ideal output would be a simple "0" or "1", but I can definitely live with something like:

```
The computer is currently locked.
```

... as long as it doesn't change. I'm used to being forced to parse output, so one more thing like that won't make any difference. I'm just having trouble finding out how to get any kind of answer whatsoever from Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell, check if user logged in and logonui running.

```
# locked.ps1
[pscustomobject]@{locked = (quser 2>$null) -and (get-process logonui -ea 0) }
```

```
invoke-command computer01 locked.ps1

locked PSComputerName  RunspaceId
------ --------------  ----------
  True computer01      7897e551-c698-4633-a740-e8bf5e139e98
```